# Adding an Outlook 'tooltip' to mail message read area

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I'd like to have the ability to highlight a number and look it up in an external browser based system.  Is it possible to add a right-click action to Outlook and open a url using the highlighted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to add SmartTag functionality here. http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/05/02/understanding-vsto-smart-tags-and-com-smart-tags-mclean-schofield.aspx